# Error on optimization problem, maximize log determinant on CVX

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, cvx

$A$ is an $N \times N$ complex matrix
$W$ is an $N \times N$ complex matrix
$C$ is an $N \times N$ complex diagonal matrix
$u$ is a scalar
$V$ is an $N \times N$ complex matrix, whose diagonal elects are null
$P$ is a scalar

The problem is a data-rate maximization using a precoder $W$ to mitigate the crosstalk introduced by the real channel matrix $A$
[image: Optimization Problem]

Implementation:

```
cvx_begin
    variable W(N,N)
    variable u
    C = diag(diag(A*W))
    V = A*W - C

    maximize( log_det(C) )

    subject to  
        norm(W,'fro') <= u*sqrt(P)
        u^2 + (norm(V,'fro')^2)/N <= 1  
cvx_end
```

I'm getting the following errors:

CVX Warning:
   Models involving "log_det" or other functions in the log, exp, and entropy
   family are solved using an experimental successive approximation method.
   The method requires multiple calls to the solver, so it can be slow; and
   in certain cases it fails to converge. See Appendix D of the the user's
   guide for more information about this method, and for instructions on how
   to suppress this warning in the future.
Error using cvx/geo_mean (line 111)
Disciplined convex programming error:
   Invalid computation: geo_mean( {complex affine} )

Error in cvx/det_rootn (line 17)
    cvx_optval = geo_mean( diag( X ) );

Error in log_det (line 28)
cvx_optval = size(X,1)*log(det_rootn(X));

Error in optimization_problem (line 58)
    maximize( log_det(C) )

Comment: This might be a good question to ask on the CVX forum on cvxr.com.

Comment: Also, it seems that specific error is caused by the complexity of the affine argument. If $A$ is real that error does not arise (though others are present).

Comment: Thanks, I have already asked on the [CVX forum](http://ask.cvxr.com/question/781/error-on-log_det-optimization/). I did not explain in details the application, but A must be complex.